# AngularJs: "controller as" syntax - can't access data, but can't .i.invoke functions

Tags: angularjs

I "upgraded" my app from `$scope` to `controller as`. Now my HTML view can evaluate controller data, but cannot invoke controller functions. I have `console.log()`; I set  breakpoints in the functions in the developer console, but they are not invoked.

The app was working just fine before :-(   I would rather not switch back to `$scope`.

Here's the relevant code:

***config.js***

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
{
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/search");

    $stateProvider
        .state('search',
            {
                url: "/search",
                templateUrl: "views/search_view.html",
                data: { pageTitle: 'Search' },
                controller: 'Search_controller as Search_controller', 
            }
        )
        .state('search_result',
            {
                url: "/search_result",
                templateUrl: "views/search_result_view.html",
                data: { pageTitle: 'Search result' },
                controller: 'Search_result_controller as Search_result_controller',
            }
        );
};


angular.module('Enigma').config(config);
```

***View***

```
<!-- no controller on the DIV, because it is declared in the router config; see config.js -->
<div ng-init="SearchController.InitializeMap()" style="height:90%; width:100%">
    <table style=" width:100%; height:10%">
        <tr style="width:10%">
            <td style="width:1px;white-space:nowrap">Enter skills e.g ((C++ AND doors) NOT c)</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="SearchController.skillsSearch.searchText"
                    ng-change="SearchController.SearchTextChanged()" autofocus style="width:100%" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="width:10%">
            <td>Optionally enter company name(s)</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="SearchController.companySearch.searchText"
                                   ng-change="SearchController.SearchTextChanged()" style="width:100%" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="width:100%">
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"
                    ng-disabled="submitButton.disabled" ng-hide="submitButton.disabled"
                    ng-click="SearchController.SubmitSearch()">Search</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

<div>%%initalSearch=={{Search_controller.initalSearch}}%%</div>        
<div>@@{{Search_controller.statusText.text}}@@</div>
<div>++{{Search_controller.statusText.text!=""}}++</div>


        <tr ng-visible={{Search_controller.statusText.text}}!="">
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <span style="width:100%">{{SearchController.statusText.text}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span ng-show="SearchController.unemployedCandidates.length > 0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success" ng-click="SearchController.ShowHideUnemployedCandidates()">
                        {{SearchController.ShowHideUnemployedCandidatesText}}
                        {{SearchController.unemployedCandidates.length}} unemployed candidates
                    </button>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <hr>
        <div id="map" class="angular-leaflet-map"></div>
    
</div>
```

Those debug lines

```
<div>%%initalSearch=={{Search_controller.initalSearch}}%%</div>        
<div>@@{{Search_controller.statusText.text}}@@</div>
<div>++{{Search_controller.statusText.text!=""}}++</div>
```

evaluate correctly, so I have access to the controller's data, ***BUT*** none of the `ng-click` or `ng-change` functions fire.

Am I just using the wrong syntax or something? The developer console shows no errors.

Comment: Could you paste the controller code? or create a plnkr would better

Comment: The controller is huge. Let's just say that I have functions, shown in the HTML, with no parameters. The first line is `console.log()` and I set a breakpoint there. No log, no breakpoint hit. I am hoping that I made some glaring n00b mistake, that someone can spot instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in the template, it should be Search_controller instead of SearchController.

change:

```
ng-click="SearchController.SubmitSearch()"
```

To:

```
ng-click="Search_controller.SubmitSearch()"
```